# How do you implement an interface with a generic utilizing IComparable to another class?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

```
    public interface ITree <T> where T: IComparable
    { 
        public Boolean isEmpty();
        public int cardinality();
        public Boolean member(T element);
        public NonEmptyTree<T> Add(T element);
    }
```

I keep getting an error below when I try to implement ITree... I am implementing ALL methods

```
public class EmptyTree<T> : ITree<T> //I get error
    {
        public EmptyTree()
        {
        }
```

The error message I get is the type t cannot be used as type parameter there is no boxing conversion

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: You've failed to include the error message, but I'm going to guess it's due to lack of generic constraint on the second class' `T`.

Comment: @TheGeneral haha :)

Comment: The compiler is complaining about `public class EmptyTree<T> : ITree<T> where T : IComparable` However my spidey senses tell me you actually want to use the generic variant  `IComparable<T>`

Comment: Please don't paraphrase error messages.  It's hard to help with an error without seeing the original error message. Please edit your post to include the exact wording of any error message, as well as which line of code the error points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

So I used the below to implement the interface to my NonEmptyTree class. It doesn't throw any error messages, so I essentially wanted to implement Tree interface where T extends comparable.

```
   public class EmptyTree<T>: ITree<T> where T: IComparable
```